# Exporting individual class members is not allowed

Tags: c++, c++-modules

With modules, why doesn't the standard allow this?

```cpp
struct T
{
    export void func();
};
```

If you have forward declared `T` and have a `std::unique_ptr<T>` why shouldn't you be allowed to call member functions of `T` with `->`?

Will this be coming in the future?

---

I suppose this is because we cant forward declare member functions https://youtu.be/tjSuKOz5HK4?t=865

UFC would help maybe https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2019/04/13/ufcs-history/

I'm kind of tempted to start writing all public member functions as free functions i.e. `void func(T* self, ...)`. Are people doing this?

Comment: If you're getting build errors, then please try to create a [mre] to show us. And copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build-log into the question as well.

Comment: "Are people doing this?" Yes